# BinaryNet implementation in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, quantization

I recently read a very interesting paper (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.02830v3.pdf) suggesting a method for training a CNN with weights and activations constrained to [-1,1]. 
This is highly beneficial from power/speed perspective.

There are implementations for the method in Torch and Theano publicly available in github:
https://github.com/MatthieuCourbariaux/BinaryNet  (Theano)
https://github.com/itayhubara/BinaryNet  (Torch)

I was wondering if the above method can be implemented in TensorFlow ?
Has anyone tried implementing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the TensorFlow [GitHub issue #1592](http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1592). It tracks the progress of the current attempt to add support for binary networks in TensorFlow.